# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 -Java Adapter Invocation Client Side

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

The following is an addition program to add two numbers.

my Server-side coding and Client-side coding as follows.
it throws error like

> ReferenceError: com is not defined at (compiled_code):24

To work with Java Adapter Http Adapter is mandatory.

Server.js and client.js as follows

```
package com.mss;
public class Calculator {
public int addTwoIntegers(String first, String second){
    int c=Integer.parseInt(first)+Integer.parseInt(second);
   return Integer.toString(c);
}
```

}

```
function addTwoIntegers(){
alert("hi");
var calcInstance = new com.mss.Calculator();   
  return {
    result : calcInstance.addTwoIntegers("1","2")
  };
```

}

Comment: Server.js? can u explain what is this server.js

Comment: @Idan Adar not server.js it is serverside java code i.e Calculator.java. And Client.js means client side javascript.

Comment: So edit your question to make sense.

Comment: @Vinod You cannot call java class directly from client side. For that only you need adapter. Whatever you have written in client.js has to be in adapter.

Comment: @sasi do you mean above two  piece of code must be in server side only.

Comment: @Vinod Yeah it has to be.

Comment: @sasi How can we create server side javascript. How do we call those js functions.

Comment: @sasi Could you please let me know how do we create serverside js how do we make call those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To work with Java Adapter Http Adapter is mandatory

The above sentence in false. In MFP 7.0 you have both *JavaScript* adapters and *Java* adapters. To use a Java adapter you are *not required* to use HTTP adapter. That doesn't make sense. They are two different types of adapters.

Read the following tutorials: [Server-side development](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/)

Have you taken a look at the *UsingJavaInAdapter* adapter in [the Adapters sample](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/)? It demonstrates exactly what you're trying to do.

---

Did you actually create such a `com.mss` Java class and placed it in the server\java folder of your MFP project?

The question is just missing information.
[Read the Java in JavaScript adapters tutorials](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/).

---

**Java class**

```
package com.sample.customcode;

public class Calculator {

    // Add two integers.
    public static int addTwoIntegers(int first, int second){
        return first + second;
    }

    // Subtract two integers.
    public int subtractTwoIntegers(int first, int second){
        return first - second;
    }
}
```

**Adapter implementation**

```
function addTwoIntegers(a,b){
    return {
        result: com.sample.customcode.Calculator.addTwoIntegers(a,b)
    };
}

function subtractTwoIntegers(a,b){
    var calcInstance = new com.sample.customcode.Calculator();  
    return {
        result : calcInstance.subtractTwoIntegers(a,b)
    };
}
```